# WP-PostRatings: list current user's rated posts

Tags: wpdb, plugin-wp-postratings

I've found this code to get a list of the current user's rated post, but is not working. plugin WP-PostRatings 1.85 / WP 4.9.7

Any idea?

```
<?php
global $wpdb, $current_user;
$userranking = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT * FROM wp_ratings WHERE rating_userid=$current_user->ID ");
if($userranking) {
foreach ( $userranking as $userranking ) {
echo "<li><a class='rankedposttitle' href='".get_permalink($userranking->rating_postid). "'>" .get_the_title($userranking->rating_postid). "</a></li>";
}
}
?>
```

I've also tried:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_ratings WHERE rating_userid LIKE  '$current_user-    >ID'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {

 echo $result->name;
}
?>
```

Not working, all my voters are wordpress suscribers, that should be logged in to vote.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Plugin questions are best asked on the plugin's support forum.

But this code is wrong:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {

 echo $result->name;
}
```

The foreach is backwards. Go for this (corrected $result to $result**s** in the first line - added 's'):

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {

 echo $result->name;
}
```

Your first code block has the same problem. The return value of the query is an array. You need to loop through each item in the array. I do something like this for my old eyes;

```
$results = somearray();
foreach ($results as $item) {
   // do something with $item, an element in the array
}
```

(Typos....urk...sometimes hard to see after looking at the code all day long...)